# Compare 2 strings PHP

Tags: php

Helllo, I wonder if there is a way to compare two strings and get the number of different letters (or any other metrics of difference). strcmp() doesn't really work, since it return some random numbers, which I can't use. My goal is to compare two strings and find if they are different in more than 5 symbols. Can someone give me a hint. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have examples?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like one of the rare occasions where [`levenshtein()`](http://php.net/manual/function.levenshtein.php) can be used.

> The Levenshtein distance is defined as the minimal number of characters you have to replace, insert or delete to transform *str1* into *str2*.

Comment: This is exactly what I used for one of my search functions, however I compared percent difference based on string length rather than total number of changes.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [PHP's similar_text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function:

```
$matching_char_count = similar_text($var_1, $var_2, $percent); 
echo $matching_char_count;
echo $percent;
```

Comment: Doesn't really work well with "special" cases. `similar_text("fffffoo", "foo")` returns 3 just like `similar_text("foo", "foo")`